# SIM800L power interface

Tags: power-supply, gsm

I would like to use SIM800L for M2M. I have power of 5V 2A for powering uC board and would like to add gsm module. It seems that SIM800L has rather strange voltage input rating: 3.4V - 4.4V.
What would be proper way to power it up with this configuration?

One proposal was to use zener diode with VF 1V, is this viable solution?

Comment: What is that strange input rating, 3,4V ~ 4.5V?

Comment: Yes 3.4V ~ 4.4V

Comment: I think that Voltage range is so it will work with a LiPo battery with no regulator as a LiPo is generally in the range of 3.7V - 4.2V 3.7V nominal and 4.2V when charging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a stable 4V from you 5V supply with voltage regulator, like TI's [lm2596s](http://www.ti.com/product/LM2596?keyMatch=lm2596s-adj/nopb&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything).
It has an adjustable output version which is capable of driving a max 3A load with excellent line and load regulation, beside providing the adjusted fix voltage (like 4V in your case).

I have used this IC with my GSM module which has similar supply voltage ranges like yours (3.4V - 4.6V, 4 recommended), it works fine.

Though, it requires more components and more space than a single zener diode, I think it is more reliable.

[image]

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) has a good Design Component Selection Guide. Also, you can request [samples](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2596/samplebuy) if you have an educational or company e-mail address.

Comment: No samples for educational users these days from TI it seems :(

Comment: Unfortunetely yes. From 2015 1st of November there are no more samples for educational users, only for companies. Dark day in cheap home proto-typing.